# Calculate height between 3 vertices

Tags: 3d

I have three points that lie on a plane $(p_{1x}, p_{1y}, h_1),\,(p_{2x},p_{2y},h_2),\,(p_{3x},p_{3y},h_3)$.

I know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a fourth point $(p_{4x}, p_{4y})$, but need to find the corresponding $z$ value (I.e. $h_4$) so that this point lies on the same plane as the first three points.

How do I find $h_4$?

[image: sketch]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean: I have three points that lie on a plane $(p_{1x}, p_{1y}, h_1),\,(p_{2x},p_{2y},h_2),\,(p_{3x},p_{3y},h_3)$. I know the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of a fourth point $(p_{4x}, p_{4y})$, but need to find the corresponding $z$ value (I.e. $h_4$) so that this point lies on the same plane as the first three points. How do I find $h_4$?

Answer (score 1):

If you compute the [barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) of $p_4$ with respect to $p_1,p_2,p_3$.
i.e the three numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3$ such that
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 1\quad\text{ and }\quad p_4 = a_1 p_1 + a_2 p_2 + a_3 p_3$$
$h_4$ will be equal to $a_1 h_1 + a_2 h_2 + a_3 h_3$.

To compute $a_1, a_2, a_3$, you can use the fact they are proportional to the area of triangles $\triangle p_4 p_2 p_3$, $\triangle p_4 p_3 p_1$ and $\triangle p_4 p_2 p_3$. More precisely, if $(x_i,y_i)$ are the coordinates for $p_i$ where $1 \le i \le 4$, we have

$$a_1 : a_2 : a_3\; = \;
\left|\begin{matrix}
x_4 & y_4 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
:
\left|\begin{matrix}
x_4 & y_4 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
:
\left|\begin{matrix}
x_4 & y_4 & 1\\
x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

Comment: Thanks. But im not good in math. Can you write simple formula which i can use in my program?

Comment: @Tito100 I don't see anyway to have very simple formula, you could use following formula to implement a function to compute the determinant $$\left|\begin{matrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1\\
x_2 & y_2 & 1\\
x_3 & y_3 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right| =
(x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1) + 
(x_2 y_3 - x_3 y_2) + 
(x_3 y_1 - x_1 y_3)$$